# Group function in where IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have two tables having seq_no column:

```
select max(SEQ_NO) from final_prices;
select max(SEQ_NO) from price_loads;
```

I want to insert into a third table: archive_load from final_prices table on the condition that if the MAX(SEQ_NO) in final_prices exists in price_loads table

I am writing this query:

```
insert
into xx_label_prices_arc_temp
    (select * from xx_label_final_prices where max (seq_no) in (select max(seq_no) from xx_label_price_loads));
```

It gives me the error:

> group function is not allowed here

How can I insert based on this logic?

Comment: Does MAX(SEQ_NO) from final_prices also need to be MAX(SEQ_NO) from price_loads or does it just need to exist?  Are you wanting to insert all rows from final prices if this condition is met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
insert into xx_label_prices_arc_temp
select *
from final_prices
where exists (
  select 1 from price_loads where seq_no = (select max(seq_no) from final_prices)
)
```